# My duck is stuck: gltf object from three.js loader appears not to redraw

Tags: three.js, mesh, gltf

I'm trying to make a simpler version of the [threejs glTF loader example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html), loading just the duck. [Here's what I've got](http://files.aaroncurt.is/duck/). If you click and drag, my OrbitControls rotate the camera and the cube appears to rotate in response. The duck, however, just hovers, phantasmic, in the upper half of the window and just says put. What have I done wrong? I want the duck to behave the same as the cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add `THREE.glTFShaders.update(scene, camera);` into my `animate()` function.

Comment: In newer versions of three.js (i.e. r85+) this shader update is no longer necessary.